# jquery selector : select first div with a specific class after some element

Tags: jquery, selector

How can i select the first div with a specific class with jquery?

Ex : i want to put some html in the first p tag when i click on the first a.a_preview etc...

```
<a href="#" class="a_preview">Preview</a><br />
<div class="preview_div><p>Some text</p></div>

<a href="#" class="a_preview">Preview</a><br />
<div class="preview_div><p>Some text</p></div>

<a href="#" class="a_preview">Preview</a><br />
<div class="preview_div><p>Some text</p></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".a_preview").click (function (e) {

$(this).nextUntil("a").find("p").html("aaaaa");
});
```

http://jsbin.com/imavug/edit#javascript,html

Comment: @adokara p.s. next time use http://jsbin.com/imavug/2/edit wrappers. that way - youll have isolation to each section and youll have more intuitive way of finding each element.